# Visual Studio debug on device

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-virtual-device

I am trying to connect my own Google Nexus 5 so that i can debug my Xamarin code from visual studio with it. I have downloaded all the drivers and all that. When i type in

```
    adb -d devices
```

it finds my phone. I can do all sorts of things with it from there so the phone is for sure connected to the computer. My problem is how i get the stupid AVD manager to realize that? It just won't find my phone.

PS i know this might not be the right forum for this so plz send me to the right one

Comment: Did you select the Android-project as StartUp Project? And what is it saying as soon as you deploy it (right-click on Android-project and click deploy)

Comment: Well yeah but i am trying to get it to connect to the AVD manager. For now i can only use the slow emulators and it just can't find my device at all.

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing your AVD Manager at all, if you click on Debug/Start it should be building and deploying the app on your mobile device immediately.